# Test users and unpublished Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-test-users

Just a quick question - I seem unable to access my unpublished Page using a test user that I've created for an app I'm developing. This app is tied to the unpublished Page as a tab, and every time I try to navigate to the Page with a test user I'm redirected back to the test user's wall.

As a test I published the Page and this time I was able to get to the app using the test user.

Surely we can test our Page and Apps together using test user accounts, whilst keeping the Page and Apps in a sandboxed state?

Cheers

Lee